# Request for member 'start' in 'processingThread', which is of non-class type

Tags: c++

I have written a class called ProcessingThread, where I pass a boost:circular buffer with the help of a shared pointer:

```
#ifndef PROCESSING_THREAD_H__
#define PROCESSING_THREAD_H__

#ifndef BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK
    #define BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK
#endif

#include <bitset>
#include <thread>
#include "boost/circular_buffer.hpp"

using namespace boost;


class ProcessingThread{
public:
    ProcessingThread(std::shared_ptr<circular_buffer<std::bitset<32>>> cBuffer) : circularBuffer(cBuffer), processingThread() {}
    ~ProcessingThread();
    void start();
private:
    void threadMain();

    std::shared_ptr<circular_buffer<std::bitset<32>>> circularBuffer;
    std::thread processingThread;

};

#endif
```

With the following implementation:

```
#include "processingThread.h"


ProcessingThread::~ProcessingThread(){
    if(this->processingThread.joinable()){
        this->processingThread.join();
    }
}


void ProcessingThread::start(){
    this->processingThread = std::thread(&ProcessingThread::threadMain, this);
}


void ProcessingThread::threadMain(){
    //TODO some stuff
}
```

And finally, I create a class instance and call start(). This is where the error appears:

```
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>
#include "boost/circular_buffer.hpp"
#include "processingThread.h"

using namespace boost;
using namespace std;

int main(){
    circular_buffer<bitset<32>> circularBuffer(4000);
    ProcessingThread processingThread(std::shared_ptr<circular_buffer<bitset<32>>>(circularBuffer));
    processingThread.start(); <--- error
}
```

The error says:

```
error: request for member ‘start’ in ‘processingThread’, which is of non-class type ‘ProcessingThread(std::shared_ptr<boost::circular_buffer<std::bitset<32ul> > >)’
```

Which is the typical error of using '.' instead of '->' when using creating the class dynamically, which is not the case.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You defined a function!

```
ProcessingThread processingThread(
    std::shared_ptr<circular_buffer<bitset<32>>>(circularBuffer) );
```

is a function which has one argument of type `std::shared_ptr<circular_buffer<bitset<32>>>`. Easy solution:

```
ProcessingThread processingThread(
    std::shared_ptr<circular_buffer<bitset<32>>> { circularBuffer } );
```

Comment: I had never heard about the most vexing parse before. Nevertheless, usiing {...} leads me to a different error: no matching function for call to ‘std::shared_ptr<boost::circular_buffer<std::bitset<32ul> > >::shared_ptr(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’. Do I need to change the class constructor declaration too?

Comment: @RomanRdgz: Sorry, I might have misunderstood your intention. You need to pass an expression between `{ }`  which is a valid initializer for `std::shared_ptr<...>`. The shared_ptr suggest you're trying to share ownership, but ownership of which buffer?

Comment: I have not shown a previous line initializating the circular_buffer called 'circularBuffer'. I am trying to share the ownership of that previously created circular_buffer, since it is to be used also at the main() method. I edited the question.

Comment: @RomanRdgz: That can't work, for unrelated reasons. (shared_ptr calls ` delete` which requires the object to be created by `new`)